# Separate image files for different folders using csv file

Tags: csv, dataset

I am using Windows and want to split a folder of images into different folders. I have a .csv file which contains information on the folder destination of the image. The file is structured as:

- file_name, label aaaa.png, 1 aaab.png, 2 aaac.png, 3 aaad.png, 4

This should be interpreted as image aaaa.png to folder 1, image aaab.png to folder 2, image aaac.png to folder 3, image aaad.png to folder 4.

please help me out

Comment: Did you find a better answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
Path2 = Path2 = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/dataset/train'
for index in data.index:
  if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(Path2, data['target'][index])):
    os.mkdir(path=os.path.join(Path2, data['target'][index]))
  shutil.copy(os.path.join(Path2, data['Image'][index]), os.path.join(Path2, data['target'][index]))
```

[data file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InK7L.png)